# Usage of explained_variance_ for sklearn.decomposition.PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-algebra, pca

I am working on some principal component analysis and I happened to run into a couple of different ways of getting eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Specifically, I found that in `scipy.sparse.linalg` there's an `eigs` method, and in `sklearn.decomposition.PCA()`, I can also get the eigenvalues by accessing the `explained_variance_` attribute.

However, I've run it a couple of times and I am getting some mismatches in eigenvalues. I understand that it's possible for eigenvectors to be different because they may be scalar multiples, but I don't understand how eigenvalues could also differ.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ll
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])
w1, v1 = ll.eigs(a, k=3)
w2 = PCA(n_components=3).fit(a).explained_variance_
```

```
w1.real
array([ 1., -1.,  0.])

w2
array([0.5       , 0.16666667, 0.        ])
```

You'll see that `w1` and `w2` have different eigenvalues. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding some basic linear algebra concepts here, or if something's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scikit-learn`'s PCA `fit()` method takes as input a dataset `X` of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` where `n_samples` is the number of samples and `n_features` is the number of features, and then decomposes the `(n_features, n_features)` covariance matrix of `X`, while `scipy`'s `eigs()` takes directly the matrix to be decomposed as input.

This means that in order to obtain similar eigenvalues you should fit `scikit-learn`'s PCA to a dataset `X` with covariance matrix close to `a`, see the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as ll
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.datasets import make_spd_matrix

# number of dimensions
n_dim = 3

# covariance matrix
a = make_spd_matrix(n_dim=n_dim, random_state=42)

# dataset with given covariance matrix
np.random.seed(42)
X = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(n_dim), cov=a, size=100000)

# decompositions
w0 = np.linalg.eig(a)[0]
w1 = ll.eigs(a, k=n_dim, return_eigenvectors=False)
w2 = PCA(n_components=n_dim).fit(X).explained_variance_

# eigenvalues
print([format(w, '.3f') for w in np.sort(w0.real)[::-1]])
print([format(w, '.3f') for w in np.sort(w1.real)[::-1]])
print([format(w, '.3f') for w in np.sort(w2.real)[::-1]])
# ['3.616', '0.841', '0.242']
# ['3.616', '0.841', '0.242']
# ['3.616', '0.841', '0.242']
```

Comment: Thanks Flavia! Just to confirm - if I have a dataset X that contains m data points with n features each (m*n matrix), if I were to use sklearn.PCA, I can actually do it directly with the dataset itself (i.e. PCA(n_components=n_dim).fit(X)). But if I were to do it with np.ll.eig or scipy.ll.eig, I would have to first figure out my covariance matrix (X-mu).dot(X-mu.T)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct.